# code from hackbook tutorial doesn't seem to work on mobiles

Tags: android, facebook

I am using code from hackbook from the official [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/) but when i test it on my mobile something weird happens.

When I first luanched, I pressed login and got the spinner but no window for login appeared. I got bacj on my starting page. Then I unistalled facebook, and everything was working fine. I installed facebook again and everything was working fine again. But then I upgraded my fb app and is not working either. I get the followning:

1)pressing the login button does nothing. Seems to loading but then i get to the same starting page
2)pressing the status update gets me a force close
3)pressing the requests asks me for login (it should have get me a warning-login required not open the login window)
4)all the other options get me the warning- please login first as the should.

has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: can you able to post image coz i am able to Login in Hackbook

Comment: on emulator i can login too. On my phone I have the problem only when my fb app is updated. So you can login in your phone? With updated facebook app?

Comment: yes i am able to login and updated facebook app means ?

Comment: ok let me explain. t was working fine on my phone. later, i downloaded from market an update for facebook, and with that version, hackbook doesn't play. You can see what is happening on the post above. It is like it is confused, some list options work, other not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is what I done. Facebook so far has problems with SSO (single Sign On- meaning with this that if you are logged in Facebook any other app that uses facebook must "see" that you are logged in'). So I disabled SSO. That means that even if you are logged in In FB, when you first launch my app you must log in again. This is how to do it:

Somewhere in your code where it does the authorization it calls:

```
mFacebook.authorize(activity, permissions, activityCode, listener); replace activityCode with FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH
```

or just google it : disable SSO

Here is an interesting link that suggests how to setup SSO properly which didn't work for me either, so I went with option number 2- disabling the SSO.

[Link](http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with not getting past the first screen, logging in did nothing.

The solution for me was changing the Hackbook AppID with the ID of my own program (got the ID from making a new app on the developers.facebook.com page.

After that, the app worked much better. Still some 'unfortunately, Hackbook for Android has stopped' errors, but at least one step further.