# Facebook login does not persist

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

**Background**

I have just downloaded Facebook Android SDK from GitHub (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) and import the SDK and Hackbook sample code.

---

**Problem**

When running Hackbook sample project as-is, the user login doesn't persist, i.e. every time I exit and restart the app, I have to log in again.

---

**Desired Outcome**

The user should not need to login every time the app starts, the saved Facebook token should work as intended.

Comment: possible duplicate of [code from hackbook tutorial doesn't seem to work on mobiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056546/code-from-hackbook-tutorial-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-mobiles)

Comment: @AvadhaniY Please actually read the two questions, they are completely different. Mine's about login state not preserved, that question is about unable to login in the first place. I've done searches before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the access token in mobile itself using SharedPrefrences and use that everytime while using the app.

Also check for the expiration of the access token. IF expired try to get new access token using a refresh token and follow the same 1st step ie saving it in mobile itself  through Shared Preferences.

Hope it helps

Comment: The sample provided with the SDK already does this, the access was indeed saved and retrieved and the expiration date wasn't over either, but somehow it would be rejected by the SDK.